# How to use page based pagination In API Platform in graphql

Tags: symfony, graphql, api-platform.com

I want to be able to paginate with `https://api-platform.com/` and the graphql support.

I enabled pagination and I only can use those params :

> first: Int Returns the first n elements from the list.
>
> last: Int     Returns the last n elements from the list.
>
> before: String     Returns the elements in the list that come before
>   the specified cursor.
>
> after: String     Returns the elements in the list that come after the
>   specified cursor.

The thing is that with those params I cannot access to a page 5 from the first page for example. For that I would need to know the cursor of the last element of the 4th page.

Do I missunderstand the possibilities of that system ?

Is there a way to use a param such as `offset` with which I could easily start after the N first elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot apply the same page-based behavior for a cursor-based pagination. The concept of "page" doesn't exist so it makes no sense to ask for a specific page.

However, in the master version of API Platform (no release yet), you can enable a page-based pagination for GraphQL.

The documentation is here: https://api-platform.com/docs/master/core/graphql/#using-the-page-based-pagination.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain me why an `offset` param would break the cursor based concept ?

Comment: Because an offset doesn't make sense in a cursor-based pagination.
You are not requesting the elements after n elements but elements after a cursor.
The number of elements before the cursor may vary rapidly and the cursor allows to pinpoint where you are without worrying if the elements before it have increased.

Comment: Please read https://medium.com/@meganchang_96378/why-facebook-says-cursor-pagination-is-the-greatest-d6b98d86b6c0 for more information.